# rails: how to add child association through a text field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two models: Company and Person

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc {|attrs| attrs.all? {|k,v| v.blank? } }
end
```

And my HTML form partial for new and edit actions looks like this:

```
<% form_for(@company) do |company_f| %>
  <p>
    <b>Name</b><br />
    <%= company_f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <ul>
    <%= render :partial => 'person_fields', :collection => @company.people, :locals => {:company_f => company_f} %>
    <%= link_to_add_fields(:people, company_f) %>
  </ul>

  <p>
    <%= company_f.submit "Submit" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

where "_person_fields" partial looks like this:

```
<li>
  <% company_f.fields_for :people, person_fields do |person_f| %>
    <%= person_f.label :name %>
    <%= person_f.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

At the moment, if I typed in person_f.text_fiel :name the name of the person, and hit save, a new Person model with that name gets created. Not what I want at all, I already HAVE that person's Person model in the database, I rather want to ASSOCIATE this person to this company.

Another thing is that I wouldn't mind using the name for human-friendly identification of the person rather than id like this for the "_person_fields" partial

```
<li>
  <% company_f.fields_for :people, person_fields do |person_f| %>
    <%= person_f.label :id %>
    <%= person_f.text_field :id %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

this by the way, doesn't work either. when I hit submit, nothing happens. nothing gets saved or changed or anything.

So I thought, just for the sake of experiment, say I did use id's for identification for a Person model, (so that I don't have to go in to autocomplete with a hidden id field which I am using for another project. I hate it). All I want is: go to a new/edit Company page, there's a bunch of textfields for me to type in ids of people, and save and then these people are then associated with the company. I mean, it's exactly like

```
people = Person.find(1,2,3)
#=>["romeo","juliet","henry"]
company = Company.first
#=>["Shakespeare Co."]
company.people<<people
company.people
#=>["romeo","juliet","henry"]
```

And it'd be best if I didn't have to use select menus because eventually if the project takes off and I have a thousand people, that's too big for any select menu. I know then I will have to use autocomplete + hidden id field that gets set when a person's name is chosen.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :people` defines `people_attributes` and `people_attributes=` methods in your Company model. Those two methods are used when you have `fields_for :people` in form. As stated in [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132) (read whole page, not only method definition):

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent.

It doesn't work to associate two objects, that can be done without it, you still have `people` method in Company.

[Formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) for example uses select with multiple attribute (you can check more than one option with ctrl) or list of check_boxes (easier for normal user, don't have to touch keyboard).

If you want to use autocomplete, it could be done, but you need to append your ids to `people[]` array (don't remember format right now, I'll check later. You can check its format when you create attribute in your form for `:people` I think)

*Edit:*
I think I know hot to do it simple way (without autocomplete, simple html only).

In your `companies/edit` (or `new`) view place:

```
<p>
  <%= company_f.label :people %>
  <%= company_f.collection_select :person_ids, Person.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true} %>
</p>
```

That will allow you to select multiple people to company (with Ctrl). Params generated by this part transfered to your controller should now look like:

```
"company"=>{"name"=>"CompanyA", "person_ids"=>["1", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"4"
```

If you want to show people with checkboxes I managed to get it with this (I copied part of markup from [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)):

```
<ul>
  <% Person.all.each do |person| %>
    <li>
      <%= check_box :person, :id, {:name => "company[person_ids][]", :checked => @company.people.include?(person) }, person.id, nil %>
      <%= person.name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I had no time today to check how to do it with hidden fields, so you can use autocomplete, but I believe that it should be similar to checkboxes - you need to use something which adds `<input type="hidden" name="company[person_ids][]" value="#{person.id}">` for every autocompleted person, and also need to create initial list of people already in company (**YOU OVERRIDE THE LIST**, not add to list).

---

If you want field to add or remove (separate fields, sorry) people from company, then this should work:

in Company model:

```
def add_people=(people_ids)
  ids = people_ids.split(/,/).map(&:to_i)
  person_ids += ids if ids
end
def add_people
  ""
end
def remove_people=(people_ids)
  ids = people_ids.split(/,/).map(&:to_i)
  person_ids -= ids if ids
end
def remove_people
  ""
end
```

and in your new/edit view:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :add_people %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :add_people %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :remove_people %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :remove_people %>
</p>
```

Now all you need to do is to find JavaScript for auto-complete, connect it to ids and names of all people (probably `PeopleController#index, :format => :json` should be good) and tell it to fill those text_fields (can be hidden fields if you would use autocomplete).

This approach should work, because you define virtual attributes in company model, and by assigning to them string in format `"1, 2, 6"`, you add/remove those ids from your collection of associated people

Comment: Does that mean you have to use form_tag or text_field_tag instead of company_f.text_field for the "people_ids[]"?

Because we might have many contractors and selecting the from a drop down menu or check box isn't very efficient.

Comment: Hey MBO thanks for the solution for the adding and removing person in the company's new/edit form. I thought of that but in a much, much less specific way. So thank you for materializing it here alongside your detailed walkthrough.